# Collections of sets that are not classes

Tags: logic, set-theory

In (ZFC-based) set theory textbooks, classes are defined as collections of sets that are definable by a first-order formula. Working *outside* a model, $M\models$ ZFC, one can obtain collections of sets which are not classes: e.g. $\{n<\omega:n\text{ is the Godel number of sentence satisfied by }M\}$ (Tarski's theorem).

Is there a standard term for such collections (since the words *set* and *class* already have meanings).

Comment: In the context of ZFC, classes would usually be defined as collections of sets that are definable by a first-order formula *with parameters*. So Tarski's theorem does not apply here. The set of Gödel numbers of sentences true in $M$ may or may not be a class of $M$; it depends on the particular $M$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Maybe this example works. Enumerate the model, $M=\{m_\alpha:\alpha<\kappa\}$. Then we should be able to enumerate all formulas *with parameters* from $M$, like $\{\phi_\alpha(x):\alpha<\kappa\}$. Now let $C=\{m\in M:\exists\alpha<\kappa(m=m_\alpha\land M\not\models\phi_\alpha(m_\alpha))\}$. If $C$ were a class, then for some $\alpha<\kappa$, we would have  $C=\{m\in M:M\models\phi_\alpha(m)\}$. However, this implies a contradiction: $m_\alpha\in C\Leftrightarrow m_\alpha\notin C$. Hence, $C$ is not a class.

Comment: Also, it occurs to me that there is a simpler argument just using the fact that $|\mathcal{P}(M)|$ is greater than the number of formulas with parameters from $M$.

Comment: Your two comments are essentially the same. $|\mathcal P(M)|>|M|$ is usually proved by a diagonal argument, and your previous comment spells out that argument. Back to your original question: I'm not aware of a more efficient way to say "parametrically undefinable subset of the model $M$".

Comment: I see, maybe there is no term in common use. The only thing I don't like about "parametrically undefinable subset" is that is contains the word "set". I think that could be confusing, since it is not a set (i.e. it does not correspond to a point of $M$).